# Displaying a disabled modal form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to disable a `TForm`'s descendant and showing it as a modal form.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm : TMyForm;
begin
  Frm := TMyForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Frm.Enabled := False;
    Frm.ShowModal();
  finally
    Frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

At runtime, it raises the following error message:

[image: Picture of the error saying "Cannot make a visible window modal"]

> Cannot make a visible window modal.

Comment: Why do you want to display a disabled form modally?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Because it contains some informations that sometimes I need to display without allowing the user to click or change anything

Comment: Then disabling it is the wrong thing to do. How do you display the information? If you are using `TEdit`, `TMemo`, or `TRichEdit` controls, you should simply set them to read only. Otherwise, if you have some combinations of various controls like radio buttons, you should disable each and every such control, not the form itself. I mean, surely you still want the `Cancel` button to be useful? In addition, disabling the form instead of the actual controls will make the controls *look* enabled, which is very confusing! That's an important point.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I thought to override the form's `SetEnabled` method in order to change the controls inside the form accordingly with the form's `Enabled` value. Probably it's not the best approach to the problem, but I think the message is very strange (note that if you check for `Frm.Visible` before calling `ShowModal`, you will see that it's `False`)

Comment: Yes, the message is a bit confusing, but in any case you shouldn't do this. I mean, surely you want the user to be able to close the dialog?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Sure. It's a side effect that I had not considered at the beginning. As you suggested in the answer, I'll surely create a special method for disabling the controls inside the form, instead of disabling the form. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP wants to display a disabled form modally when the form should be displayed for read-only purposes.

Disabling the form is the wrong thing to do.

How do you display the information? If you are using `TEdit`, `TMemo`, or `TRichEdit` controls, you should simply set them to read only. Otherwise, if you have some combinations of various controls like radio buttons, you should disable each and every such control, not the form itself. I mean, surely you still want the **Cancel** button to be enabled?

In addition, disabling the form instead of the actual controls will make the controls *look* enabled, which is very confusing! That's an important point.

So what you need to do is to display the form normally (not disabled!) and then set its *controls* to their appropriate states when the dialog is shown.

---

Just to emphasise my point about disabling the form vs its controls, consider this dialog box:

[image: Screenshot of a standard dialog box.]

If I do

```pascal
procedure TCustomViewFrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Enabled := False;
end;
```

then it looks like this when shown:

[image: Screenshot of the form displayed when disabled. It looks exactly like it did in the last screenshot! Nothing looks disabled!]

As you can see, every control looks very enabled indeed, but no control responds to mouse or keyboard input. This is very confusing and a horribly bad UX.

In fact, you cannot even close the dialog box using its title-bar Close button or Alt+F4. You cannot close it using its system menu, either. In fact, you cannot close it at all, because to close a window, it must respond to user input, and a disabled window doesn't do that. (You cannot move the window, either.)

Instead, if we disable all controls (except the **Cancel** button),

```pascal
procedure DisableControl(AControl: TWinControl);
begin
  for var i := 0 to AControl.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    if
      (AControl.Controls[i] is TCustomButton)
        and
      (TCustomButton(AControl.Controls[i]).ModalResult = mrCancel)
    then
      Continue;
    if AControl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
      DisableControl(TWinControl(AControl.Controls[i]));
    AControl.Controls[i].Enabled := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomViewFrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DisableControl(Self);
end;
```

you get this nice UI:

[image: Screenshot of the form with all its controls except for the Cancel button disabled, including the labels.]

Not only is it very clear that all controls are disabled, the user can also close the dialog box without killing your application using the Task Manager.

Comment: One quick compromise is to use `TGroupBox`: disabling it automatically disables all controls inside. Bonus: in this example the group's caption could have been used for the heading already.

Comment: @AmigoJack: No, if you disable the group box, its controls still look enabled, just as in the `TForm` case. Re visuals: If you prefer the Windows 95 GUI over the Windows Vista+ GUI. (The blue text is part of the Windows Vista+ GUI guidelines.)

Comment: Everybody understood your example includes optical fixes. I say compromise because you can disable "everything" at once while the window itself remains unchanged. Even your solution has the downside that it's not readonly anymore: most disabled controls won't let you copy text anymore, which is a downside for me again.

Comment: @AmigoJack: That's true. No disabled controls let you do that.